# SMART data self test is greyed out in Disks?

Tags: disk, smart

[image]

Why is that?
It is ok for the 2nd drive which is external usb ssd.

Comment: Probably your SSD does not support S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: The problem is the USB adapter.

Comment: its a built it nvme ssd in lenovo x1 yoga laptop
the other is external ssd drive which is fine and can run a SMART. But yeah the one that is grayed out is the main OS partition and is mounted

Answer (score 17):

From [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 18.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/868179#868179):

> ### SMART option greyed out
>
> This can happen with NVMe SSD's. You need to install NVMe SSD specific
>   SMART tools:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install nvme-cli
> ```
>
> Then run the program to report health of drive:
>
> ```
> $ sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
> Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
> critical_warning                    : 0
> temperature                         : 40 C
> available_spare                     : 100%
> available_spare_threshold           : 10%
> percentage_used                     : 0%
> data_units_read                     : 28,167,888
> data_units_written                  : 19,397,424
> host_read_commands                  : 561,183,142
> host_write_commands                 : 171,788,833
> controller_busy_time                : 1,354
> power_cycles                        : 2,385
> power_on_hours                      : 1,363
> unsafe_shutdowns                    : 133
> media_errors                        : 0
> num_err_log_entries                 : 608
> Warning Temperature Time            : 0
> Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
> Temperature Sensor 1                : 40 C
> Temperature Sensor 2                : 51 C
> ```
>
> The most important data point is:
>
> ```
> percentage_used                     : 0%
> ```
>
> When it hits 100% it is time worry about replacing your drive. That
>   said this drive is two years old and still at `0%`

Comment: installing this did not fix the disabled options in the gnome app disks (ubuntu 21.04)

Comment: error -> smart-log: invalid argument

Answer (score 2):

NVME Support was added to smartmontools starting from version 6.5. Please note, that currently NVMe support is considered as experimental.

You can check your current version with the command `apt-cache policy smartmontools`

The latest version for 16.04 LTS in the repositories ATM is [6.4+svn4214-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=smartmontools&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) which doesn't have this feature. However it appears that the [versions available for artful, bionic and cosmic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=smartmontools) do have it. Newer packages can often be found [here.](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Packages) Alternatively, you can [install from source](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#Installfromthesourcetarball) or try a [daily build.](https://builds.smartmontools.org/)

For more details on the current status of NVMe support in `smartmontools` check [the wiki.](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/NVMe_Support)

Info on USB SMART support in `smartmontools` can be found [here.](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/USB)

Answer (score 1):

Not all USB adapters support SMART. I have 2: one of them supports it, the other one not. Both of them USB3

Answer (score 0):

In my computer I have

- an **nvme** drive
- Lubuntu **18.04.x** LTS with

  - **Disks** version 3.28.3 - the "S.M.A.R.T. data self test" is greyed out.
  - **smartmontools** version 6.5+svn4324-1 - the "SMART overall-health self-assessment test" works.

So I suggest that you install the package `smartmontools` and use the tool `smartctl`.

Comment: OP is on Ubuntu 16.04 (at time of writing question in 2017). Will the new version install on an old LTS? Also is there a link to product description with screenshots?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, Good catch about the version :-) I am not sure if the new version installs on an old LTS. But the test can be done from a newer Ubuntu version running live (without installing nvme-cli). Still  Disks has it greyed out for nvme. -- What product description are you asking for (the nvme or the connecting chain PCI-e card, motherboard)?