# Ubuntu crashes after few minutes of boot

Tags: crash

This happened consistently, after every reboot. I couldn't identify an event that cause it, even happened if I haven't log in.

In the beginning everything seems fine, and I still have commands like ls and ps, but after a few minutes pass Ubuntu starts to crash. First Gnome looses icon layouts and I can't access ls and ps, because Ubuntu can't find the executables.
Then I got to the login screen and I can't login with the message: authentication error.

Then I got to a screen where these messages loops forever(at least for 10 minutes it does, after that I turned off the machine with the power button)

[The screen I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIzgg.jpg)

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad L590 with
CPU: intel core i7-8565u 1.8 Ghz
Mem: Samsung ddr4 16 GB 
Storage: Intel SSDPEKKF512G8L

I already tried the in-built hardware diagnostics, except the extended memory check(I will do that this night but it estimated it to run for 6 hours, so I thought first I should check other things). From the run tests everything passed.

What can cause this issue?

Comment: @user535733 changed the link thanks for noticing

Comment: Read-only filesystem. Usually means hardware fault (dying hard drive). Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive.

Comment: you need to boot from an usb to run the SMART test and the other tools.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix the file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p1`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Windows**

If you've installed any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions, uninstall it asap, as it's what's been corrupting your SSD.

**Check SMART**

Start the `Disks` application. Select your SSD, then review the SMART Data & Tests window. Edit your question and post screenshot(s) of the data.

**Check your BIOS**

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` # should be 117

https://support.lenovo.com/by/en/downloads/ds540054 to download the newer version.

**Check nvme firmware**

`sudo lshw -C disk` # identify firmware version for Intel SSD

Then go to the Intel site and check for newer firmware for the SSDPEKKF512G8L

**Check memory**

Run your internal memory test, or go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

Lenovo is sending a replacement nvme drive.

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, but every test passed. I tried the smart test as well with a bootable USB, but the button was greyed out, so I skipped that, but found this: https://askubuntu.com/q/909823/1052040 and did these steps. For me it showed that nothing was wrong. It turned out one of my colleague had the same issue with her laptop, where the SSD was malfunctioning. After reinstalling Ubuntu, the problem still occurred, so I reported the issue to Lenovo support and they are sending a new SSD tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kovi Did you check the nvme firmware (and the BIOS)?