# Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade getting stuck with fsck check

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 20.04, fsck

My problem is similar if not identical to [Ubuntu 20.04, every boot makes a very long filesystem check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237389/ubuntu-20-04-every-boot-makes-a-very-long-filesystem-check/1260660#1260660) having insufficient reputation to comment for joining the club.

Dual boot Linux/Windows system on an HP SSD equipped notebook using grub boot loader. Worked perfectly with 19.04. Did an upgrade to 20.04 shortly after release. On second (??) reboot after the grub screen a file system check message containing a spinner showed up endlessly. Moreover the promised »Ctrl-C« to interrupt did not work at all.

I then re-installed 19.04 working perfectly again. Today reaching 19.04 end of support I thought 20.04 might have improved but to no avail! The spinner turned endlessly again »Ctrl-C« not helping an inch.

Strangely the very first reboot after upgrading to 20.04 succeeded: I saw the file system check message disappearing after five seconds as expected before successfully continuing the reboot process. But on second reboot I got stuck again.

I employed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip ..."` workaround but obviously a file system check at boot time is advised.

My `/etc/fstab` contains four entries corresponding to `/`, `/boot/efi`, `/home` and swap:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=ca0eb0c0-9606-41e4-873f-de0e3ba10266 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=288C-F264  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=743bb313-9845-4aed-a1ad-6b97ed4fac01 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=f0f43222-3cdb-4059-acfc-af13b09190d9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`fdisk -l` relevant portion:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953,89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: KXG50ZNV1T02 TOSHIBA                    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 12EEC9A1-6277-423E-B253-0B603CF869C7

Device             Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1023999    1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1024000    1228799     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1228800    1261567     showing 32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1261568  204802047  203540480  97,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 204802048  206755839    1953792   954M Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p6 206755840  437909503  231153664 110,2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 437909504 2000408575 1562499072 745,1G Linux filesystem
```

Using a live boot system both `fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6` and `fsck /dev/nvme0n1p7` execute flawlessly almost immediately reporting two »clean« file systems. Forcing a file system check yields a correctable warning for the `/home` partition:

```
root@ubuntu:~# e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7
e2fsck 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 43787646 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize<y>? yes
Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/nvme0n1p7: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/nvme0n1p7: 240030/48832512 files (1.9% non-contiguous), 54063796/195312384 blocks
```

Subsequent `e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7` report no warnings.

```
tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p6

tune2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          ca0eb0c0-9606-41e4-873f-de0e3ba10266
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              7225344
Block count:              28894208
Reserved block count:     1444710
Free blocks:              23465464
Free inodes:              6742890
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Fri Apr 24 05:43:28 2020
Last mount time:          Tue Jul 21 08:18:20 2020
Last write time:          Tue Jul 21 08:18:19 2020
Mount count:              5
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Jul 21 07:30:25 2020
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          64 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      23aac590-850f-4f42-9368-55601ba5eec0
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0xbfd90acb
```

```
tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p7


tune2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /home
Filesystem UUID:          743bb313-9845-4aed-a1ad-6b97ed4fac01
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              48832512
Block count:              195312384
Reserved block count:     9765619
Free blocks:              141232260
Free inodes:              48592695
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Mon Dec 30 14:12:27 2019
Last mount time:          Tue Jul 21 08:18:21 2020
Last write time:          Tue Jul 21 08:18:21 2020
Mount count:              5
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Jul 21 07:30:33 2020
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          359 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      c6477151-86b4-4275-b627-ce2568be458f
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0xa5c6ce45
```

SMART check:

```
nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0

Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 31 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 5%
percentage_used                     : 1%
data_units_read                     : 3.459.789
data_units_written                  : 3.987.840
host_read_commands                  : 59.275.018
host_write_commands                 : 52.110.771
controller_busy_time                : 191
power_cycles                        : 863
power_on_hours                      : 1.091
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 147
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 0
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 31 C
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 0
```

Comment: Glad to see you here, and with a detailed description of the problem :-) What happens when you **force check** with `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p6` and `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7`; Will there be some warning or error output? In that case, can you repeat it until all warnings and errors disappear?

Comment: `/dev/nvme0n1p6` receives no warnings or errors. Neither does any subsequent `e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7`.

Comment: Please edit your original question to add output of commands (and render as code) in order to make it easier to read. Anyway, there seems to be no bad error. What happens after you run it? Will the file system get damaged at shutdown or at boot?

Comment: No. I rebooted the system with `... fsck.mode=skip...` still active. Then after regular shutdown again booted  by »live USB«. The `e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7` output remains clean. So shutdown and boot appear to behave fine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'still active'? Is there still an automatic file check, even with a good file system? In that case you might have a look at the settings via `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p6` and `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p7`; option: 'minus ell' to list settings. For example, look at 'Maximum mount count' and 'Check interval'

Comment: I 1. removed the grub `fsck.mode=skip` and ran `update-grub`. 2. Rebooted an USB rescue system checking  `e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p[6|7]` showing no errors or warnings. 3. Failed to reboot »normally« due to non-ending FS check message reappearing. Then the only way getting back into the system was using recovery mode re-enabling grub's `fsck.mode=skip`.

Comment: What do `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p6` and `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p7` indicate?

Comment: See updated post above.

Comment: I see no problem in the output of tune2fs. But in `man tune2fs` it says "If you are using journaling on your filesystem, your filesystem will never be marked dirty, so it will not normally be checked.  A filesystem error  detected  by  the kernel  will  still  force an fsck on the next reboot, but it may already be too late to prevent data loss at that point." Maybe this is what is happening in your case: A  filesystem error is detected at boot, and it is fixed automatically.

Comment: Mmmh. Its gotten worse: Now I see just the spinner but no fsck related message. Only recovery mode is working. Thinking about reverting to old 19.04

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 has psssed end of life and receives no updates, not even security updates. **You had better try another version. 18.04.x LTS could be better.** I'm still running a system based on 18.04.1 LTS with the kernel series 4.15 in my main computer. (But I have 20.04 LTS in a laptop, and will probably transfer to it in August also in my main computer.)

Comment: I suggest that you check the S.M.A.R.T. status of your nvme drive. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972978/fsck-reports-that-filesystem-still-has-errors/972983#972983)

Comment: I believe its a kernel Problem. I did a fresh 20.04 install. Rebooting works fine. After installing all upgrades the problem shows up with kernel 5.4.0-42. But when I choose the still existing installation image 5.4.0-26 kernel from the grub menu booting happens smoothly. Also newer kernel versions e.g. 5.7.9 do not work.

Comment: **That's a good job tracking down the problem :-)** But still, it is worthwhile checking the S.M.A.R.T. status of your nvme drive. Maybe the new kernel finds a real problem there, maybe the new kernel just cannot manage your nvme drive or some software to connect to it (for example a hardware driver). Anyway, if 18.04.1 LTS works for you, it is a good alternative, becasue it will **not** be upgraded to or beyond 5.4.0-42 automatically.

Comment: SMART test was greyed out in `gnome-disks` but https://askubuntu.com/questions/909823/smart-data-self-test-is-greyed-out-in-disks#1191538 pointing to package `nvme-cli` worked, see above. So far I can see no errors despite having no clue about the `unsafe_shutdowns' relevance. Since I also got stuck once without any fsck related message I have a feeling the whole thing *may* not be related to the disk at all. But how to get log information when the system is still inaccessible and disks are presumably not yet mounted?.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot about that thread. Anyway, you fixed a test. Maybe you can find something in the log files. Maybe [this link about `dmesg.log`](https://superuser.com/questions/176165/where-linux-places-the-messages-of-boot) will help you find something. Otherwise, search the internet for 'linux startup log files' (without quotes) or some similar search string, and you will find several good links.